# Permission denied error with django-celery-beat despite --schedulers flag

Tags: django, docker, celery, celerybeat, django-celery-beat

I am running Django, Celery, and RabbitMQ in a Docker container.

It's all configured well and running, however when I am trying to install `django-celery-beat` I have a problem initialising the service.

Specifically, this command:

```
celery -A project beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
```

Results in this error:

```
celery.platforms.LockFailed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/src/app/celerybeat.pid'
```

When looking at causes/solutions, the permission denied error appears to occur when the default scheduler (`celery.beat.PersistentScheduler`) attempts to track of the last run times in a local shelve database file and doesn't have write access.

However, I am using `django-celery-beat` and appying the `--scheduler` flag to use the `django_celery_beat.schedulers` service that should store the schedule in the Django database and therefore not require write access.

What else could be causing this problem? / How can I debug this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

celerybeat ([celery.bin.beat](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.beat.html#celery-bin-beat)) creates a pid file where it stores process id

```
--pidfile
```

> File used to store the process pid. Defaults to celerybeat.pid.
>
> The program won’t start if this file already exists and the pid is
>   still alive.

You can leave `--pidfile=` as empty in your command but beware then it will not know if there is more than one celerybeat process active

Comment: Thanks, I thought if you changed the scheduler to be `django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler` then it doesn't create a PID as it uses the database to write run times? Have I misunderstood the purpose of the PID?

Comment: pid is process name, pid file is there to disallow running multiple of same celery beats (imagine you run command 2 times) that would cause task multiplication. Doesn't have nothing to do with actual task runs or task scheduling.

Comment: Thanks, so in a docker environment I assume best practice would be to use a pidfile? If it's in `/usr/src/app/celerybeat.pid` shouldn't it already have write access? I am not sure how to amend the permissions after celery is substantiated if the file doesn't previously exist.

Comment: You probably want to give write access on folder of your choosing  to celery and add that folder as --pidfile